# React + Gulp + Babel (BLOAT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, babeljs

I write React with JSX, and run that through Babel for the transform, and bundle. When I look at the final output I have this repeated for each of the files I import.

```
var _createClass = (function() {...})();    
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {...}
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {...}
function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {...}
```

My [Gulpfile](https://gist.github.com/maraisr/eb32ae7acfd417c83d74), and you run `$ gulp js` should grab the files in `app/` and spit out a `public/assets/js/main.min.js` which is the final build file.

But the file is huge with all those repeated functions, how do I clean that up?

Is there another build process I should be going through? Also how would I go about pulling put jQuery, and other large libraries like that, and use them out of a CDN?

Comment: Just wondering why you are you using jQuery and React together? Doesn't make sense. I would compile my javascript and put that on a CDN rather than using public ones and global variables.

Comment: That's the problem, you can't because of scoping.. With babelify, and you require jquery, it'll say that dependancy isn't found.

Comment: But what are you using jQuery for? you don't need it for a react app, or is it used for stuff outside of the react part?

Comment: It's really besides the point....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy load images, videos, and iframes in ReactJS rendered content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356517/lazy-load-images-videos-and-iframes-in-reactjs-rendered-content)